# Dividing f(x) by zero.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm currently studying calculus, and have learned some useful facts regarding operations that can be carried out on a function. For example:

```
y = f(x) + z
```

If we plot f(x), then plot the above, the line will be moved up on the y axis by z for every z > 0, or will be moved down by z for every z < 0 relatively to f(x) line.

Similarly if I would multiply f(x) by z, the line would be moved up or down by z amount relatively to f(x) line depending if z is a negative or positive value.

But is it true to state that the following cannot be defined / ploted?

```
y = f(x) / 0
```

You cannot plot the above (I presume).

Comment: Division by zero is not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot plot $y = f(x)/0$ since it's not even defined.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct that you cannot plot $y=\frac{f(x)}{0}$, since it is not defined at $0$. Or anywhere else. Thanks Saulspatz.

Comment: Or anywhere else, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct; $f(x)/0$ cannot be plotted.  Consider the special case where $x=1$.  So then we have $f(1)$; what is this?  This is just a number.  But we can't divide a number by $0$; that value is undefined.  So we can't plot it.  And since this is true for all $x$, the entire function $f(x)/0$ isn't defined anywhere and can't be plotted anywhere.